# How To Count Total Present Attendance From Database

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table where I need to count all present to show how many attendance student have

In my table have Following Column

```
 school id
 Student id   
 year 
 Month 
 Status
 day_1
 day_2
 day_3
 To 
 day_31
```

entry goes once in a month. Like
if new month new row create
else update in day_ 1 day_2 day_3 etc.
[image: This is table to how i insert data in table]

Comment: Consider normalising your schema. Remember, a database table IS NOT a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different trick.  Although it's for MySql 8.0+

Concatinate the day_n fields into a string.
Then remove all the characters that aren't 'P' from that string.
Then the character length of the remaining string will be the total 'P'.

```
SELECT school_id, student_id, month, year, 
 CHAR_LENGTH(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
      CONCAT_WS('' -- using concat_ws because concat returns null when one of the fields is null
        , day_1
        , day_2
        -- add more day_n here
        , day_31),'[^P]+','')) AS present
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

A more conventional approach might look something like this:

```
student_id,
attendance_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can made a query to get the IDs of all students,

```
$sql2 = "SELECT distinct id from table";
$query = $this->db->query($sql2);
foreach ($query->result() as $innerrow) { 
  HERE YOU USE THE SYNTAX OF NEXT CODE-BLOCK
}
```

Inside the foreach loop you can use the id with `$row->id` to generate another sql query
with an where clause.

```
$sql = "SELECT table.* from table where id = ".$row->id;
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
  print your data
}
```

Comment: Hi its wrong sir i just need a simple query where i can count all present in my table i have  day_1 = p
 day_2 = A
 day_3 = P
 To 
 day_31     make a query for counting day_(daynumber) With all P in a Col um not Row sir

Comment: then u can use a group by for the days, select days and count p and use a select clause to only count the data which u need

Answer (score -1):

write query to find the attendance with present like

`select (if(day_1 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_2 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_3 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_4 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_5 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_6 in('P'),1,0) + if(day_7 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_8 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_9 in('P'),1,0)+....+if(day_n in('P'),1,0)) as day_present from tbl_name`

But the if condition for all 31 days or 30 days as per months days 
 just try it once in your mysql query editor You will get the exact result..

In codeigniter 
$result = $this->db->select("(if(day_1 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_2 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_3 in('P'),1,0)+if(day_4 in('P'),1,0)+........+if(day_n in('P'),1,0)) as present, school_id, student_id,year, month, status");
$this->db->get('table_name');

Comment: hi i want to count all column(day_1, day_2 , day_3 to day_31) with all P  please make proper query

Comment: just explain me that what fields you need  from database and you want that query in codeigniter or just simple query...

Comment: MY table structure  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `academic_year_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `day_1` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_2` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_3` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_4` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_5` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL     To `day_31 ` .

Comment: and data is (48, 1, 20, 3, '10', '2018', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'P', NULL, 'P', 'P', 1, '2018-10-30 16:33:30', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 0),
(49, 1, 20, 3, '11', '2018', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', NULL, 'A', 'P', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'P', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'P', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, '2018-11-01 10:46:29', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 0),

Comment: i just need to count all day_(dayvalue) who have P for a student